# Google Sign-In: how to easily decode token when using dialogflow-fulfillment library instead of actions-on-google?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I need to get the email address from Google user's profile.

I'm using Dialogflow and I implemented [google-sign-in procedure](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) to get the `Client ID` (issued by Google to your Actions), and I'm also fulfilling `actions.intent.SIGN_IN` intent (as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#account_sign-in)). I do receive the Google ID token that contains the user's Google profile information, the problem is about decoding the token.

If I were using [Actions on Google client library for Node.js](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs), I could just follow the example from [google-sign-in authentication flow](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in):

> If you use the Actions on Google client library for Node.js, **it takes care of validating and decoding the token for you, and gives you access to the profile content**, as shown in the following code snippet:

```js
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow({
  // REPLACE THE PLACEHOLDER WITH THE CLIENT_ID OF YOUR ACTIONS PROJECT
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
})

// Intent that starts the account linking flow.
app.intent('Start Signin', conv => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'))
})

// Create a Dialogflow intent with the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event.
app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const payload = conv.user.profile.payload
    conv.ask(`I got your account details, ${payload.name}. What do you want to do next?`)
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`)
  }
})
```

The problem is that I'm using [Dialogflow Fulfillment Library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs#setup-instructions) (because I'm working with Google Assistant **and** with other integrations as well).

From their sample code, I'm following this approach using the `WebhookClient`:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

function someIntent(agent) {
  if (agent.requestSource === agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE) {
    // let conv = agent.conv( );
    // do some google specific stuff... conv.ask( ... );
    agent.add('You came from Actions on Google');
  } else {
    agent.add('You came from any other source...');
  }
}

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  let intentMap = new Map( );
  intentMap.set('some-intent', someIntent);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**So, the question is**: Is it possible to pass my `clientId` (from my actions project) to `dialogflow-fulfillment` for it to decode the token (just as `actions-on-google` does)?

ps: I know there are JWT-decoding libraries and a [suggested procedure](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in#start_the_authentication_flow) I could follow to validate and decode the token. But since `dialogflow-fulfillment` I guess uses `actions-on-google` internally somehow, I'm just wondering whether there's a much easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** ***EDIT:*** **

This is even shorter and seems like the proper way to do it. Taken from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library , Node.js example:

```js
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
async function verify() {
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,  // <-- this comes from: conv.user.profile.token
      audience: CLIENT_ID,  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
      // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
      //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]
  });
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  const userid = payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //const domain = payload['hd'];
}
verify().catch(console.error);
```

** ***ORIGINAL ANSWER:*** **

**TL;DR**

```js
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const CLIENT_ID = '<your own actions client id>.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
...
// Then, on intent fulfillment method:
    let conv = agent.conv( );  // Get Actions on Google library conversation object
    let payload = await conv.user._verifyProfile(client, CLIENT_ID); // payload.email
```

**Longer story:**

Thanks to [@RezaNasiri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463329/2619537)'s link to [Using a Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library), I ended up searching where in [`actions-on-google`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) source code `google-auth-library` was used.

I found out that google [Conversation](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/src/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.ts#L178) object has an [User](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/src/service/actionssdk/conversation/user.ts#L153) object, which includes a [`_verifyProfile`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/src/service/actionssdk/conversation/user.ts#L153) method. It's supposed to be hidden, though, so be careful when using this with a different library version.

So, if using [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs#setup-instructions) webhook client:

```js
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
```

You need to add `google-auth-library`:

```js
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const CLIENT_ID = '<your own client id>.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
```

Then you can verify and decode the token like this. Here, `signInGetData` is the fulfillment method for the `actions.intent.SIGN_IN` intent:

```js
async function signInGetData(agent) {
  let ctx = agent.context.get('actions_intent_sign_in');
  let signin = ctx.parameters.SIGN_IN;
  let conv = agent.conv( );  // Get Actions on Google library conversation object

  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    // let idToken = conv.user.profile.token; // here's the token, but we don't need it
    let payload = await conv.user._verifyProfile(client, CLIENT_ID); // <<-- HERE
    if ( payload.email ) {
      conv.ask(`Got your email: ${payload.email}`);
    } else {
      conv.ask(`Got profile but not authorized to get your email...`)
    }
  } else {
    conv.ask(`No access to user data. Never mind...`)
  }
  agent.add(conv);
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what you did here? I tried the same procedure and get this error : Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience at OAuth2Client.<anonymous>
What Linking type did you use on the google action console?

Comment: @SimonSchubert I'm using "Google Sign In" linking type, not the oAuth type.  As I understand, the audience is the Client ID assigned to your Actions project (it's the ID given to you in the last step when configuring the linking type on AOG console, and the `CLIENT_ID` in the code above). It only occurs to me you might be using an invalid client id?  That's the only configurable thing here, and that might explain the `anonymous ` in the error you get.

Comment: @SimonSchubert I thought of something else. I'm using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable on CLI when testing locally. This is correctly setting the `projectId` when reading the service account credentials from a json file. When running from the firebase server, the `projectId` is detected automatically. You might be having a mismatch between your `CLIENT_ID` and the `projectId` that is being detected when you run your code, that's why your audiences don't match.

Comment: Jap, I was mismatching the client_id and projectId. Got it working now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SimonSchubert  I'm glad you do :-)  On the other hand, I've still got it implemented this way, but later I found a proper way to do it. If you're still working on it, you should follow this procedure instead. You just need to change a couple of lines, no big deal: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library  That way you use `verifyIdToken` from `google-auth-library` instead of calling the private `_verifyProfile`

Comment: Hi guys this is great stuff hours looking to found this, just a quick question, how are you doing the request to sign in?  I'm using this fulfillment without success:

const requestSignIn = agent => {
  let conv = agent.conv();
  conv.ask(new SignIn("To get your account details"));
  agent.add(conv);
};

Comment: @GreivinLópez Something like this might help you:
```const { SignIn } = require('actions-on-google');
let conv = agent.conv( );
// request sign in only if we don't have a token, and we haven't been rejected already
if ( !parameters._rejected && !(conv.user && conv.user.profile && conv.user.profile.token) ) {
  conv.ask( new SignIn('Some text here') );
  agent.add(conv);
}```

`parameters._rejected` is some internal parameter I've stored not to request sign in twice

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For some reason I'm still getting the malformed webhook error, I know sometimes is due to a simple JavaScript code error but this time it seems to be something else. I will keep trying.

Comment: @maganap I keep getting the webhook malformed error, I believe the problem is I'm not setting the client ID on that code?. Your code works perfectly for retrieving the user email (what I needed) and I think sign in will be mandatory for my use case anyway so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know the token verification is done in Dialogflow class in actions-on-google which handles all actions and communication with Dialogflow's API. That is replaced with WebhookClient in Dialogflow Fulfillment library which doesn't do that. You can check out this link for [token verification](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).